# How and Where to Call Dispose in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dispose

I was reading on how to use dispose on flutter but I cannot figure it out.  If I call the below pagedispose function after Navigator.pushReplacementNamed, I am always getting an error.  If I call this function from another class page, I then get errors that it doesn't exist etc.

Would appreciate your guidance on how to clear all running functions etc on a page when transitioning to another Flutter page.

```
@override
void pagedispose(){   
    vtimer.cancel();   
    vcontroller.dispose();   
    super.dispose();   
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html)

### dispose method

> Called when this object is removed from the tree permanently.

Regarding a page, the dispose method is called when the page is removed from the navigation stack. [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) is a good explanation of `Navigation`.
When your widget (page) extends `StatefulWidget`, it's not mandatory but you can override the `dispose` method to execute additional instructions depending on your need. The method is called automatically when the page is being removed from navigation tree. Override the method as following

```
@override
void dispose() {
  // your desired instructions here

  super.dispose(); // This will free the memory space allocated to the page
}
```

Nonetheless, the method `void pagedispose()` cannot be overridden as it ain't a known method of `StatefulWidget`

Comment: Hi dm_tr.  Appreciate the input.  Just the clarify, super.dispose is not enabled by default?  So it is best practice to always have void dispose() with super.dispose?

Comment: @marcusaureliusbrutus `super.dispose` is called by default when the function is not overridden

Comment: bare in mind that currently `dispose` is not guaranteed to be called. there's an ongoing discussion regarding this on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40940